# Pasting in their appropriate fields

Tags: autohotkey

I have a request i want a script which can paste the copied values into their appropriate fields i have 30 fields in total

the script i want is need be like this(or if can make it somewhat easy that goes, i'm not saying make it for me i don't know how to begin the script, just need some help with how to write the starting point of the script)

First (have a look at the image [Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMAZa.png)) i want to have all fields in the script and after that i'll copy some excel values (4 cells in total or three goes too) [Errors 4 Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anqmp.png) after i copied the values it need to paste the values to there appropriate fields

the fields can moved(changed) by tabs or mouseclick

Just give me some hint on how can i store the fields name in ahk script and search for the the particular field when i copied it in clipboard and paste

I'm new to AHK so it is somewhat hard for me to figure it out myself

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think it would be better if u read the whole question and comment, I clearly said that I'm not asking somebody to write the whole script what I need is which I don't know how can I store the values of field names in objects and if I copied some values it need to search for the field name and go to that particular field, just tell me is it possible or not

Answer (score 0):

The first comment on your post is likely a pre-canned response pasted in full, due to the problem/question being poorly worded and extremely difficult to follow or understand what you're trying to do.

In my limited understanding however, I believe this can be done in Excel VBA or in AutoHotkey--I would suggest starting with Excel VBA since your data is already in Excel and there is a much lower bar to start directly running code against the data in your spreadsheet.

You will want to familiarize yourself with `Range` objects and iterating through a range of cells in VBA--there are plenty of coding examples available for various purposes.  You may also want to familiarize yourself with the `HLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` functions.

Keep in mind that although these functions may be used in the spreadsheet itself (in a single cell to perform a lookup for example), you will probably want to code a macro in VBA to have the power and flexibility needed to load data, sort it (or do a lookup) and save it into the final location it needs to go.

One thing that may be possible to leverage with your data sets (notionally an input data set and and output/composite data set) would be to have two separate worksheets.  One worksheet would hold the limited set of input data that needs to be sorted, and a second worksheet in the same Excel workbook file would hold the composite output data set.  Sorting the data from the input sheet and placing it on the output sheet would need to be programmed in VBA according to the particular rules or formulas you establish.  The macro would need to iterate through the list of data rows on the input data set, figure out what to do with each of them, and then populate the data into appropriate columns on the output data set.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good with English grammar, I want it done it autohotkey, the problem is how I can put my fields names in objects and after I copied the cells it has(script) to search for the particular field and go there after that I can do the rest of the scripting

Comment: I have to paste the data in web application that is why I Need it in ahk

Comment: This is going to be a pretty challenging endeavor if you are new to AutoHotkey.  If the field names are static in the web app--i.e., they remain in a fixed location relative to one another--and if you can start the 'Paste' operation in the web app at the same column, then hard code them into an array.  For each 'Paste' operation into the web app, you will then need to iterate through the array using a loop, index the array to see what the column is, and paste something in (or not) for that column.

Comment: As it relates to 'copying' the data, it will probably be easiest to select (shade) the active cells you want to copy in Excel and then use a COM Object to iterate through the active Range and read the data directly out of the active worksheet.  I believe attempting to use the clipboard otherwise (for accessing data from multiple cells) would be more difficult.

Comment: Yeah! To me it's hard, presently I am doing single cell manually but if I succeed in making that script I would be great, as u said in your previous comment, I don't know how to hard code in a array and make it search for the field I copied

Comment: Maybe it takes some time but I'll make the script